# Web services Session Management

Tags: android, wcf, session

I am using wcf Restful web services that will be used by android application. These are secure services like only login user can hit the calls, so to acquire this I create a session when a user login and return this to user. Now problem is that how this token is passed to services so web services can verify the user session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, when User get the session token it store on client side and in next request user will send it in request Header which will be extract and verified at server

```
 HttpRequestMessageProperty messageProperty =
                    (HttpRequestMessageProperty)
                    OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
token = messageProperty.Headers[TokenName];
```

before completing required request and if session authenticated request will be completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cookies` to pass the information as long as your service is set to [ASP.NET compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) .

```
<system.serviceModel>        
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! services are for android application and I am testing these services on fiddler.